# Vectorise sum across certain columns of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, sum, vectorization

I would like to optimise the sum across certain columns of a pandas data frame by using vectorisation.
In detail, I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [1, 3, 2], data = {'Low':[1, 1, 1], 'Mid':[2, 2, 6], 'High':[3, 3, 3]})
```

and I have created a new column with the sum across the first *N* columns, where *N* is the index value:

```
df['new_col'] = [df.iloc[i,:df.index[i]].sum() for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

The final data frame looks like this:

```
    Low  Mid  High  new_col
 1    1    2     3        1
 3    1    2     3        6
 2    1    6     3        7
```

Clearly this must be vectorised. I would really appreciate any hints that will allow me to avoid the for loop.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try broadcasting the indexes and compare to the column numbers:

```
df['new_col'] = df.where(df.index.values[:,None] > np.arange(df.shape[1]), 0).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
   Low  Mid  High  new_col
1    1    2     3        1
3    1    2     3        6
2    1    6     3        7
```

Comment: Well this is a great idea! Thanks @Quang Hoang. However, I believe it should be np.arange(df.shape[1])+1?